# With SQL can you use a sub-query in a WHERE LIKE clause?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm not even sure how to even phrase this as it sounds weird conceptually, but I'll give it a try. Basically I'm looking for a way to create a query that is essentially a WHERE IN LIKE SELECT statement.

As an example, if I wanted to find all user records with a hotmail.com email address, I could do something like:

```
SELECT UserEmail 
FROM Users 
WHERE (UserEmail LIKE '%hotmail.com')
```

But what if I wanted to use a subquery as the matching criteria? Something like this:

```
SELECT UserEmail 
FROM Users 
WHERE (UserEmail LIKE (SELECT '%'+ Domain FROM Domains))
```

Is that even possible? If so, what's the right syntax?

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
SELECT  u.*
FROM    Users u INNER JOIN
        Domains d ON u.UserEmail LIKE '%'+ d.Domain
```

Or even try

```
SELECT  u.*
FROM    Users u
WHERE   EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Domains d WHERE u.UserEmail LIKE '%' + d.Domain)
```

Comment: with this you will get row repeated N times depend on how much records from right table found.

Comment: That depends on if the right table conatains the same Domain multiple times, which can be avoided using a DISTINCT subselect.

Comment: @zerkms, I added a second option for the OP to evaluate. Hope that clears things up X-)

Comment: ah, you write the same i wrote in the same time %) so i'm deleting then and giving +1 back ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Although

```
SELECT  u.UserMail
FROM    Users u
WHERE   EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Domains d WHERE u.UserEmail LIKE '%' + d.Domain)
```

will give what you look for, please realise that like is expensive and that you could shave off a bit of time with (mysql dialect):

```
SELECT  u.UserMail
FROM    Users u
WHERE   SUBSTRING_INDEX(u.UserMail, '@', -1) IN (SELECT d.Domain FROM Domains)
```

or even

```
SELECT  u.UserMail
FROM    Users u
        INNER JOIN Domains d ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(u.UserMail, '@', -1) = d.Domain
```

(and that you could split e-mail into username and domain fields if this is a common operation in your database)

EDIT: I missed the MS SQL server tag. For that dialect

```
substring(UserMail, charindex('@', UserMail) + 1, len(UserMail) - charindex('@', UserMail) )
```

should outperform LIKE (because it will be performed once per row in Users and the you get to straight join, where the like approach will have to be performed for each value in Users on each row in Domains).

P.S. check my formulas for start and length in substring (it was Friday night yesterday).