# Using [like] like in clause in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
USE tempdb

CREATE TABLE A
(
     id INT,
     a_desc VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO A 
VALUES (1, 'vish'),(2,'hp'),(3,'IBM'),(4,'google')

SELECT * FROM A

CREATE TABLE B
(
     id INT,
     b_desc VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO B 
VALUES (1, 'IBM[SR4040][SR3939]'),(2,'hp[GR3939]')

SELECT * FROM B

SELECT * 
FROM A 
WHERE a_desc LIKE (SELECT b_desc FROM B) -- IN with LIKE problem here
```

all the time the ending string is not same in table B so I can't use trim approach to
delete certain character and match in In clause.

-- above throwing error subquery returned more than 1 value

-- I've thousand rows in both tables just for example purpose I've created this example

```
--excepted output 
--IBM
--hp
```

--from A table

Comment: There are already a couple of such questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735117/using-like-and-in-and-a-subquery-in-a-single-sql-statement - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618912/like-using-subquery-returning-multiple-rows - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528858/with-sql-can-you-use-a-sub-query-in-a-where-like-clause

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM B
    WHERE b_desc LIKE '%' + a_desc + '%'
)
```

**Output:**

```
id          a_desc
----------- ----------
2           hp
3           IBM
```

**Execution plan:**

[image: proff]

**Extended statistics:**

[image: stat]

**Update:**

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM A
OUTER APPLY (
     SELECT * 
     FROM B
     WHERE b_desc LIKE '%' + a_desc + '%' 
) B
WHERE b_desc IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: For best understanding execution plan read this short manual: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/understanding-query-plans

Comment: Is it possible to get column from table B in select list with A?

Answer (score 3):

you can simple join:

```
SELECT distinct a.* 
from A inner join b on b.b_desc like '%' + a.a_desc + '%'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, this will give you the exact output

```
select distinct a.a_desc 
from A r 
join B b
on b.b_desc like  a.a_desc +'%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM A , B
WHERE a_desc LIKE '%' + b_desc + '%'
```